# How can I make 'rm' move files to the trash can?

Tags: command-line, automation, macos

I use the terminal on a daily basis, I will often use `rm DirectoryName`. Sometimes I get a little impatient and do `rm *` without deliberating if it’s safe. As you can imagine, these shenanigans have sometimes come back and hit me in the face. Does anyone know how I create a mapping so `rm whatever` moves everything to the trashcan which I then delete manually.

Comment: you can do `mv /file/to/delete ~./Trash`

Comment: It's hard to put training wheels on a precision tool like rm without breaking other scripts. Something like `alias rm=/bin/rm -i` should get you back to safety. Also - which Trash directory do you want rm to use? It gets clunky since Mac OS X has a trash directory for each volume as well as a user level trash can.

Comment: If you use zsh, by default it will prompt you when you do `rm *` or `rm /path/*`

Comment: Apologies for my dramatic comment, but the very question scares me since you can do a lot of damage with rm if you don’t have any backups in place or ability to reinstall a machine.

Comment: I want to apologize as well, my comment added drama and used “ableist” words that don’t help nearly as much as they can hurt others. I’ve edited several comments so that the “warning / danger” signal remains, but the personification of a tool is removed.

Comment: `/bin/rm -rf -i` will erase directories without prompting first.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

### Bad Idea

Using `rm` to move files to the trash is a dopamine hit. It is common and pleasuring but ***can be bad for you*** taken out of context.

You really need control yourself when using `rm`. Especially if your backups are not current or you don’t have the time to do an erase / install / restore.

---

### Don't use *rm*

**Imagine**, you get used to *rm moving to trash* and make a habit of it. Sure, your system is safe but when you log into a friend's (or your wife's or your boss') notebook and have to delete something? You'll be actually using the real `rm` - deleting those files forever. Without lots of prep and qualifiers, it's a bad habit, and you need to know that.

So instead, install `rmtrash` and make a habit of using it:

```bsh
# install rmtrash, (either from the macports or by the brew.)
$ alias trash="rmtrash"
$ alias   del="rmtrash"       # del / trash are shorter than rmtrash
```

---

### Correcting bad habits

Here’s where the personal advice starts - changing one’s behavior is hard.
Another thing you can do to force yourself to use `rmtrash` instead of `rm` is alias it to a custom message in your `.profile`.

```bsh
alias rm="echo Use 'del', or the full path i.e. '/bin/rm'"
```

So, whenever you use `rm`, you'll be prompted to either use `rmtrash` or `/bin/rm`. Remember, this is only temporary, after a while you should remove the alias.

---

Never ever, do something like this:

```bsh
$ pwd
/
$ cd /tnp; rm -rf *
sh: cd: /tnp: No such file or directory
```

*Pop Quiz: In what directory will the `rm`command run?* :)

Comment: `&&` is your lifeline. `;` is the devil. P.S. The answer is that pretty much everything on your system disappears, in the above example.

Comment: Although, rm doesnt do secure delete, but moving to trash / empty does (in my setup) .

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu users install `trash-cli` instead, ex. `aptitude install trash-cli` - see https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli

Comment: @jm666 Also check out **trash** ([blog post](http://hasseg.org/blog/post/406/trash-files-from-the-os-x-command-line/) &
 [source](https://github.com/ali-rantakari/trash)). It asks Finder for trashing files. Moreover it can also use standard Objective C filesystem APIs (faster) and fallback to Finder if insufficient rights. [`brew install trash`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/trash.rb)

Comment: `rmtrash` is really old, having been last updated in 2003, and it shows. It has many fewer options than `rm`, and if you say `rmtrash` on a secondary volume it *moves* those files to your user's trash folder on the system drive, which can take a long time for large files. The `trash` option recommended by parth is better, solving the keep-on-same-volume problem, but still missing many `rm` options.

Comment: The best solution i found was : "rm-trash" , with ppa : nateshmbhat/rm-trash

Comment: For those on macOS: `rmtrash` is no longer to be found on homebrew, so I recommend installing `trash` instead: `brew install trash`.

Comment: However looking at the code trash changed from using Finder by default to just moving to ~/.Trash

Comment: `cd /tnp; rm -rf *` hell command

Comment: This is a textbook great SE answer.

Answer (score 26):

I can think of a dozen ways to code this, but categorically refuse to type any of them up in an answer. I **strongly** recommend you curb your habit of *getting a little crazy*. You shouldn't be in the habit of using `rm` at all if you can't use it properly.

The fundamental problem here is that even if you install a safety net on your own system, that will only help you keep your bad habits and when you happen to be on another machine some day that doesn't have the same custom protections, you will do something epicly bad.

The proper solution is to use `rm` as it was meant to be used including manually adding the `-i` argument whenever you are in doubt about how a glob will expand, and have good system backups that you can restore in the event of serious user error. Trying to add "trash" to commands that in the rest of the universe don't use it is a half-way step that is the worst of both worlds.

***Either use the trash or don't.*** Using `rm` doesn't go to trash, it removes.

If you want to use the trash, there is nothing wrong with that. Just get in the habit of using the `rmtrash` command instead of `rm`. This will help your brain understand what's happening and not get you into a bad habit that will cause grief later.

Comment: Your point doesn't compute in this instance. People delete things accidentally on a daily basis, system backups do not work in the case of a home pc (which mine is) as the resources are limited, a move to trash can is a far more efficient way of handling these deletions for my particular use case.

Comment: @steve you missed the point entirely. `rm` by definition removes a file from the disk. It doesn't send it to the trash. Teaching yourself to use `rm` when you mean _send to trash_ sets you up for disaster. If you want to send to trash, use `rmtrash` or a program that was designed for the job, then you won't run into nightmares later. I wasn't saying using the trash is inherently wrong, but if you want to use it, don't wire it up to something that was not intended to use it!

Comment: `brew install rmtrash` and stop using `rm`

Comment: This is an awesome answer, cleared up a few things for me. I'll try to form a habit of using `rmtrash` instead of `rm`.

Comment: " rm by definition removes a file from the disk."

No. rm unlinks the file. It does not remove it.

Comment: @Brian You are welcome to `alias rm=ul` if you prefer to be pedantic. I understand what happens at the file system level and at least some of the physics of spinning rust (not so much some of the newer mediums), and know that `rm` doesn't scrub the bits. But for an end user with a habit of getting crazy with `rm` (**remove**) I think the correct answer is to tell them to stop using the remove command if they want a trash bucket to easily recover stuff out of.

Comment: the `rmtrash` recipe is no longer on `brew`. I suggest the `trash` utility instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use a command line tool like [rmtrash](http://www.nightproductions.net/cli.htm) (which usually just moves the file(s) to ~/.Trash making sure that the file has a unique name) or a script that uses appscript to call the Finder to do the delete. The latter is slower but adds the ability to use the Put Back option fromn Finder to restore the file easily.

I used [trash](https://github.com/ali-rantakari/trash) as it is in in MacPorts and Homebrew and rmtrash is now very old and unmaintained. However on reading the code changes when editing this note I noticed that it changed in 2017 from using the Finder by default to move by default (which is not what I wanted and is a major change). So I will look for another tool.

As noted in the comments it is not a good idea to make rm an alias best to remember to use the trash program you installed directly

But if you wanted to you could do

After installing rmtrash to say /usr/local/bin/rmtrash then you can  create an alias for bash

```
alias rm='rmtrash'
```

You can use `\rm` to call rm directly and ignore the alias

Comment: If you do use a tool like `rmtrash`, please do yourself a favor and **use it by it's own name**. Never alias things that are not `rm` to `rm`, it will some day bite you.

Comment: `rmtrash` isn't compatible with `rm` (doesn't support the same command line parameters like `-r`) so an alias really isn't useful in any case

Comment: It's a bad idea to alias `rmtrash` to `rm`. Not only they are not compatible, but also it'll enforce the bad habit and you'll accidentally use `rm` in another system thinking you are only using `rmtrash`.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add a helpful habit to get into for those that don't do this already.  Before using rm for anything, do 'ls' on it first.  That way you can see all the files that you intend to delete.  Then instead of retyping, just pull previous 'ls' command up and swap out ls for rm. This habit has reduced a lot of anxiety when invoking rm.

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to protect yourself from horrible outcomes from `rm`. However, I agree with the other commenters here: very few are any good.

Do not for a minute believe that changing the command environment will help you. For example, you will find people online everywhere recommend doing this sort of thing:

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

or

```
function rm()
{
    echo >&2 'rm forbidden; use "/bin/rm"'
}
export -f rm
```

This will not work. Period. There are loads of use cases where these little parlor tricks will fail you miserably.

The only robust way I have used to spare myself from the danger of `rm` is by setting up a regular backup process through cron over the directories where I work.  Raw UNIX does it for you nicely, with great simplicity, using `find` in conjunction with `-mtime` to check for files that have been updated within or since a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

### **Introduction (you can skip it)**

For me `rm -i` would be enough, because it prompts you before deleting any file. However, some extra security provided by `safe-rm` isn't a bad idea at all.

A simple `alias` like `rm=safe-rm -i` *could* be enough, however `rm -rf` would not work, because `-i` is overriden by `-f`.

So, we have to make sure that `-i` always come after `-f`!

---

### **My solution (3 steps):**

- Install safe-rm: `brew install safe-rm`

  You can still work with `rm`, but you have modify the `RM_BIN` in the next step
- Edit your `~/.profile` (or bash_profile or whatever), and put the following code snippet, (which contain an `alias` and a `function`):

  ```
  alias rm="rm_i"

  function rm_i(){
  RM_BIN=safe-rm # you can replace it with regular rm if you like

  args=""
  files=""
  argsDone=0 # to make sure arguments are before the files

  for var in "$@"
  do
      if [[ $var == \-* ]] ; then
          if [ $argsDone -eq 1 ] ; then
              $RM_BIN # just to show the usage of rm
              return
          fi
          args+=" $var"
      else
          argsDone=1
          files+=" $var"
      fi
  done

  args+=" -i" # Put -i at the end (so rm -rf will not ignore it)

  $RM_BIN $args $files
  }
  ```
- **Finally**, `logout` and `login`, so the updates in the .profile are applied. **DON'T** use it before a logout/login!

---

### **Notes:**

- It can be applied to any Linux distro, with slight modifications.
- It does NOT move your staff to thrash. It just asks you before deleting each file!
- It works with `-rf` and with regexes.
- If you really want to use `rm -rf` **WITHOUT** being asked for every single file/folder you can still use `/bin/rm -rf` (or `safe-rm -rf` if you had installed it).
- **No more unintentional** `rm -rf` **or** `rm *` ;)

Comment: Aliasing rm to anything larger than itself (e.g. `alias rm='sudo rm'`) is like strapping a Uzi to a kitchen knife: someday you will get more than you bargained for when you go to cut that pineapple. Aliasing rm to anything smaller than itself (e.g. `alias rm='rmtrash'`) is like letting your children play with disarmed hand grenades and not teaching them what they actually are: someday when they encounter a real one they won't treat it with the proper caution. **Either way—aliasing rm is bad for sys admins as lack of hygiene is to personal safety and public health!**

Comment: Using something like safe-rm is reasonable advice. Aliasing it to rm is not. Use it under its own name or a unique alias so you don't take for granted a safety net that will not always be there.

Comment: I see your point. BUT, the reason I did this, is that I work with many terminals.. some remote terminals, and some locals. And I want to throw lot of **grenades** on the remote terminals, but when I accidentally pull the **safety seal** on the local terminal, I want to see a **warning** before the **explosion** occurs.

Comment: @Paschalis and what happens if a script or installed program needs to use `rm`? Also, Caleb's point is even more valid -- if you get used to a system with safe-rm aliased, then you might get reckless with it and eventually use it on a system with an unaliased rm.

Comment: Also be aware that there are several different incarnations of  safe-rm. A ZSH plugin to move files to trash, a Perl script to blacklist important folders etc and a Rust  version of the same.

Answer (score -1):

Mac bigSur

```
brew install trash

alias rm='trash'
which rm

touch a.md
rm a.md
ls ~/.Trash
```

Comment: Why does this only work on Big Sur?